# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am currently coding my discord bot I have already set these moderation and fun functions for her, I wanted my bot to make music so I made my orders but I stumble on a problem and I can't find where this comes, so i turn to you hoping that you can help me. here is my code:

```
exports.run(message) {
  const serverQueue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
  if (serverQueue && serverQueue.playing) {
    serverQueue.playing = false;
    serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.pause();
    return message.channel.send("⏸ La musique est en pause !")
  }
  return message.channel.send(
    "Il n'y a aucune musique qui est en train de jouer !"
  );
}


module.exports = Pause;
```

Comment: Yes, `exports.run(message) {` … `}` is invalid JavaScript syntax. Looks like you wanted `exports.run((message) => {` … `});` or something instead.

Comment: `exports.run(message) {` is the problem. If `.run()` expects a function, then you need a complete function declaration.

Comment: Time to learn how to use a code linter to show you where syntax errors occur. If you aren't familiar with one's in your code editor you can use online ones. Once you see where the error is you can then check the documentation for correct usage

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the Arrow Function (`=>`)

```js
exports.run(message) => {
  const serverQueue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
  if (serverQueue && serverQueue.playing) {
    serverQueue.playing = false;
    serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.pause();
    return message.channel.send("⏸ La musique est en pause !")
  }
  return message.channel.send(
    "Il n'y a aucune musique qui est en train de jouer !"
  );
}


module.exports = Pause;
```

Please consider learning JavaScript and to find Errors yourself.

Comment: I found my error and its working I did this : `exports.run = (message) => {`